# PerformanceNavigationTiming type "back_forward" doesn't show up most of the times

Tags: javascript

I am trying to detect whether a user clicked the back button then forward button back to the current page, but it doesn't work:

```js
const entries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");
entries.forEach((entry) => {
  alert(entry.type);
});
```

When I click refresh it works and shows `reload`. When I first come to the page it also works and shows `navigate`.

But when I click the back and forward button, most of the times it won't alert `back_forward`. Only on some random times it does show `back_forward` (I only managed to see `back_forward` twice and I am not sure why it worked in these times)

The snippet doesn't really work here because it's not run on load, so it can't really be tested here.